# Is there any function in tensorflow for getting all the hyperparameters or options from the model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, hyperparameters

In the sklearn library after declaring the model-

```
model1 = sklearn.svm.SVC()
model2 = sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge()
```

We can directly get available hyperparameters by using `model.get_params()`, is there anything like this in tensorflow? Additionally if we even load the pre-built model which already have these hyperparameters set, can we get them?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Keras using :

```
model.get_config()
```

You can also see the model architecture using :

```
model.summary()
```